# even distribution of LIs not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, html-lists, text-alignment

I'm trying to justify / distribute my `LI`s in my `UL`, and I have managed to do so in all browsers except IE7. Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xmu9P/12/) in IE7 and any other browser - only in IE7 it fails to spread (the navigation `UL`s are the *Hiya Hola Bonjour Ni Hao Yo!* and *Cookie Cheese Mangoes Underwear*).

I'm using the [IE7 JS Library](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), so my usage of `:after` is not the issue. Neither is my usage of `inherit`.

An image detailing the issue (take note that the words differ in the JSFiddle and the screencap below):

[image]

I've been cracking my head for hours. Could anyone nudge me in the right direction please? Thank you! :)

P.S. It isn't exactly pretty yet, but the colours are just to clarify, should you question my taste :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay me, I found the answer.

I removed `display:inline-block, zoom:1, *display:inline` from the `UL.justify` (effectively making it a `display:block`), and added `-ms-text-justify:distribute-all-lines; text-justify:distribute-all-lines`. I added `text-align: left` to the `LI`s, et voìla, it is working well in **all browsers**.

Should you want to use `:after` in IE7, I would recommend the [IE7 JS Library](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). However, should you want to do this without having to rely on Javascript (I subscribe to that school of thought generally, but not in this case), you can use a conditional comment targeted on `lt IE8` to display `<div class="justifyAfter"></div>`.

Hope this is of use to anyone :)

Here's the code:

```
/* Navigation */
nav li {
    display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;
    text-align: left;
}

.justify {
    text-align: justify; -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines; text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

.justify:after, . justifyAfter {
    content: "";
    display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}
```